# Cordova WebView slower than Android WebChromeClient

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, webview, angular-material

Yesterday I tried using Phonegap with a web app that uses angularjs and angular material. The performance is very slow on my device (ASUS Zenfone 5 running 5.0) including the animations and keyboard input which takes about a second before a character shows when typing. I've researched about Phonegap's performance and some says that I should try to use Crosswalk Project but still, the performance isn't good.

To my curiosity, I built an android app which uses the Android native WebView that uses WebChromeClient and the performance is better than a Phonegap + Crosswalk, but why? Isn't Phonegap also uses the Android native WebView then just load the site as an asset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Phonegap/Cordova use the Chrome webview. By using Crosswalk, you ensure that you always use the latest Chrome webview, independent of what Chrome version is actually installed on your phone.

It could (but I think it's unlikely) lead to a difference in performance. What I expect however, is that some Cordova plugin you loaded is the culprit. I've seen (and read about) plugins that just drop the performance of your whole app.

**EDIT:**
I've only done one experiment with Angular Material myself, and I wasn't experiencing any real performance issues at the time, but I did read some people writing about it being slower than plain Ionic.

My suggestion would be to try to build an Ionic app (it's just plain Angular with performance optimizations and some handy directives). If you want to have Material Design for it, you can try [Ionic Material](https://github.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material). I made the switch to that, because I found some very hard to track issues with Angular Material, and it didn't follow the Ionic way of doing things.

Ionic Material has to easy to access documentation yet, but [their Demo](http://ionicmaterial.com/demo/) is full of code examples

Comment: I've removed the installed cordova plugins except the crosswalk but the performance is still very slow, I'm using Phonegap version 5.1.1